# Convert image to BGRA color space without using opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Is it possible to convert an RGBA image to BGRA without using the following code, i.e. without using opencv?

```
image = self.cv2.cvtColor(image, self.cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
```

Comment: sure. just numpy. some slicing and stacking and you're done. try it.

Comment: Are you allowed to use PIL? else use numpy. You just want to change the order.

Comment: https://www.scivision.dev/numpy-image-bgr-to-rgb/

Comment: Sure: for each pixel: swap R and B values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this with *"fancy indexing"*:

```
# Make a dummy, random 4-channel image
RGBA = np.random.randint(0,256,(2,3,4), np.uint8)

In [3]: RGBA
Out[3]: 
 array([[[102, 204,  36, 128],
         [178, 151, 166,  45],
         [199,  49, 104,  98]],

        [[ 79,  33, 223,  62],
         [ 26,  34, 233, 254],
         [ 62,  20,  57, 149]]], dtype=uint8)

# Convert RGBA to BGRA
BGRA = RGBA[..., [2,1,0,3]]

In [5]: BGRA
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 36, 204, 102, 128],
        [166, 151, 178,  45],
        [104,  49, 199,  98]],

       [[223,  33,  79,  62],
        [233,  34,  26, 254],
        [ 57,  20,  62, 149]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I think OpenCV likes its data contiguous, so if you get issues, use:

```
BGRA = RGBA[..., [2,1,0,3]].copy()
```

Comment: And how can you convert the BGRA image back to RGBA? thanks

Comment: You can use `RGBA = BGRA[..., [2,1,0,3]].copy()`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an image from BGRA to RGBA with this line of code:

```
image[..., :3] = image[..., 2::-1]
```

Of course, it modifies the existing array rather than creating a new one *(which is good if you don't plan on using the old one again as it's more efficient)*. Another way is `image = image[..., [2,1,0,3]]`, but since it uses fancy indexing, rather than modifying the old array, it creates a copy of the old array which takes up more memory.

Using the same line of code again converts the image back from RGBA to BGRA.

Comment: And how can you convert the BGRA image back to RGBA? thanks

Comment: @azal By using the same line of code you can convert the BGRA image back to RGBA.